# Empty request body in a nestjs guard (bug?)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```
    @Post()
    @UseGuards(
        CategoryVerificationGuard,
        VerboseAuthGuard,
        UniqueEntryTitleGuard,
    )
    @UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
        { name: AttachmentsName.IMAGES, maxCount: AttachmentMaxCount.IMAGES },
    ]))
    public async createEntry(@UploadedFiles() attachedFiles: IUploadFile[],
                             @Body() createEntryBodyDto: CreateEntryBodyDto,
                             @Headers('authorization') authHeader: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.entryService.create(getUserIdByAuthHeader(authHeader), {attachedFiles, ...createEntryBodyDto});
    }
```

The code for the guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoryVerificationGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        // private readonly categoriesService: CategoriesService,
    ) {}

    public async canActivate(ctx: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
        const requestBody: IConfirmationCodeValidation = request.body;
        const requestHeaders: IncomingHttpHeaders = request.headers;

        console.log('BODY', requestBody);
        console.log('HEADERS', requestHeaders);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I set `multipart form` I get empty body. Why does it happen? Looks like a bug.

P.S.

It is however possible to get access to headers but body is empty for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guards are activated before interceptors are. In this case, `multipart form` data is handled by the `FileInterceptor` or `FilesInterceptor` (depending on how many files are sent in). Because the body is assigned in the interceptor (due to when `multer` is called), this is the intended functionality, as the body has not been parsed by the proper middleware. You can decide to call `multer()` on your own in your `main.ts` if you prefer, depending on the incoming header type.

Comment: Mmmm I'm not sure I understand. What is `multer`? Is it something that works under the hood? Could you please elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is a multipart form data request parser, it's what Nest uses for the `FileInterceptor`/`FilesInterceptor`/`FilesFieldsInterceptor` [as said in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload). It's a standard Express middleware, similar to `body-parser`.

Comment: I've checked it, yeah seems like it's the module that works under the hood. So it seems like I can use `multer()` to access the request body inside that guard. But how do I do that exactly? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Like I said, in your `main.ts` you can call the middleware directly instead to do the parsing. If you do this, you won't need the `FileFieldsInterceptor`, just keep in mind you should verify the incoming request is `multipart/form-data` before calling the middleware. To call it, you would normally use `app.use(multer())` just like you do in express.